# I need grammatical help over here!

Tags: commas, ambiguity

I am writing a term paper and I ran into this complex sentence in an article which I cannot make sense of. I think there is something wrong with the punctuation, making it twisted. There are several _and_s and commas in a row. I do appreciate it if I could receive some help as I suspect it is not grammatically correct.

> "We derive an analytical equation for calculating the change of fundamental thickness-shear frequencies in terms of initial thermal and mechanical strains, and second and third order elastic constants, for rotated Y-Cut quartz crystals."

Comment: The author unfortunately put the prepositional phrase modifying the direct object _frequencies_ after the intervening _in terms of_ phrase. It should probably be _We derive an analytical equation for calculating the change of fundamental thickness-shear frequencies for rotated Y-Cut quartz crystals in terms of initial thermal and mechanical strains, and second and third order elastic constants._ A comma after _crystals_ would not be amiss, though it's not really necessary if you can hear the sentence in your mind's ear. Provided you're a native speaker.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sentence, aside from being rather complicated. The equation applies to rotated Y-cut quartz crystals. You put thermal strains, mechanical strains, second order elastic constants, and third order elastic constants into the equation. You get the change in thickness-shear frequencies out of the equation.

Comment: @PeterShor Comma before "for" is awkward and unnecessary. plus, I removed the comma before the second "and". I wonder if its all right now. 
"We derive an analytical equation for calculating the change of fundamental thickness-shear frequencies in terms of initial thermal and mechanical strains and the second and third order elastic constants for rotated Y-Cut quartz crystals."

Answer (score 2):

> "We derive an analytical equation for calculating the change of fundamental thickness-shear frequencies in terms of initial thermal and mechanical strains, and second and third order elastic constants, for rotated Y-Cut quartz crystals."

I will try to make this less succinct.

We derive an equation for calculating the change of frequencies.  The cast of characters in the equation will be:

- initial thermal strain
- initial mechanical strain
- second order elastic constant
- third order elastic constant

We will do this for rotated Y-Cut quartz crystals.  [Or maybe: the second and third order elastic constants we will use are the ones for rotated Y-Cut quartz crystals.]